# How do I use SQLalchemy to treat an existing select object as a view?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a `select` object `s1` and I would like to treat it as a view, so that I can join other tables onto it. I have tried something like this:

```
s1 = select([t1], ...)
s2 = s1.join(t2, t1.c.id==t2.c.id)
```

but I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: Not an executable clause
```

I have tried this:

```
s1 = select([t1], ...)
s2 = select([t1, t2], from_obj=s1.alias().join(t2, t1.c.id==t2.c.id))
```

but I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t1"
```

The reason I need to do this is because `s1` is returned from a function that applies a complex where clause and I'd rather not rebuild that where clause when constructing `s2`.